# how to calculate the angle at the center to 4 coordinates?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

given 4 coordinates, how do I calculate the angle forming at the center point?

I'm writing code in JavaScript and I have a request for rotation support with two fingers.

so, the user touch the screen with two fingers, and as he move his fingers clockwise/CC the image needs to rotate accordingly.

so the only data I have are the coordinates of the start position and the current position of the users two fingers.

I've added a link with an image for some visual explanation.

[image]

Comment: Hint: Dot product

Comment: (1) Subtract each pair of points diagonally opposite to each other. That gives you two vectors, $v,w$. (2) Their dot-product determines the angle $\frac{v\cdot w}{\sqrt{v\cdot v}\sqrt{w\cdot w}}=\cos(\text{angle})$.

Comment: Thank you @MattiP.

Comment: thank you @nextpuzzle! I'm not that good in Math, so can you please explain this in more details, for example: what do (1) means? I have no idea.. (sorry.....)

Comment: If $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are the two green points. Then $v=(x_1-x_2,y_1-y_2)$. The $w$ would be the same thing but for the blue points.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you not link to pictures. If at all possible type everything  in MathJax in your question. Failing that you can add the image file to the question so it appears with your question. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Im new so still not eligible to upload images here, only a link referring the image. I also find this unclear like this. @DanielBuck

Comment: Oh right. Then what I would do is explain the question better. i.e. two lines are formed by joining up the pairs of coordinates, and they cross each other at some point. Now you want the angle formed at this intersection. For a MathJax tutorial see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  and how to ask a good question at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Thank you for this great comment @nextpuzzle! and still, I can't understand how to break -> v=(x1−x2,y1−y2) and how go from this to -> v⋅w (bare in mind I need to write this as code on JavaScript)

Comment: @RoeyZada If $v=(a,b)$ and $w=(c,d)$, where $v,w$ are the differences above, then $v\cdot w=ac+bd$. More information about there dot product [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). Special attention to the [Algebraic definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Algebraic_definition) and the [Geometric definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) sections.

Comment: it works! .. thank you @nextpuzzle

Answer (score 2):

Let the position vectors of the four points be $\textbf{a}$, $\textbf{b}$, $\textbf{c}$, $\textbf{d}$, in anticlockwise order. Then what we have to do is to find the angle $\theta$ between the two vectors, $\textbf{a}-\textbf{c}$ and $\textbf{b}-\textbf{d}$. So
$$
\cos\theta\cdot |\textbf{a}-\textbf{c}|\cdot|\textbf{b}-\textbf{d}|=(\textbf{a}-\textbf{c})\cdot(\textbf{b}-\textbf{d})=\textbf{a}\textbf{c}+\textbf{b}\textbf{d}-\textbf{a}\textbf{d}-\textbf{c}\textbf{b}
$$
In the diagram, $\textbf{a}-\textbf{c}=(350-90,357-355)=(260,2)$, $\textbf{b}-\textbf{d}=(182,-132)$ (The diagram seems a bit off.)

$(\textbf{a}-\textbf{c})\cdot(\textbf{b}-\textbf{d})=47056$

$\cos\theta=0.8050, \theta=0.635rad$.

Since the diagram given is not completely clear, there may be some errors in the answer. But the mothod is certainly correct.

Comment: first, thank you for this wonderful comment!
Im a bit slow on math and need to translate your answer to a JavaScript code eventually. so can you please elaborate on how to calculate (a-c) * (b-d).. I don't understand how to break this -> (260, 2)